# To pause scheduleAtFixedRate Timer while the app goes in background?

Tags: java, android, timer

Here is my fixed rate timer code. Can i pause this timer while activity goes in `onPause();` . If so then what would you suggest me put in `onPause();` method and timer should start work as app comes to `onResume();`:

```
    //Declare the timer
    t = new Timer();

    //Set the schedule function and rate
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  // code here
                              }
                          },
            //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
            20000,
            //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
            40000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`Timer.cancel()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer#cancel())

- Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. Does not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists). Once a timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.

Declare the timer as global

```
t = new Timer();
```

Try this

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     t.cancel();
  }
```

> timer should start work as app comes to onResume();:

You need to start `Timer` in  `onResume()`
Try this

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      // code here
                                  }
                              },
                //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
                20000,
                //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
                40000);
    }
```

Comment: A little update needed - You need to initialize timer in onResume(); 
Else will encounter "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled"

Comment: Overall solution worked perfectly well.. Thanks Rathore Sahb :)